# Use pseudo-elements like :after with $(this)

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

For example, I have this jQuery function:

```
function example(){

  var trigger = $('.image');

  trigger.each(function(e){
    // here I want to change the background color of the :after pseudo-element
    $(this:after).css('background-color', 'red');
    // ^ the above obviously doesn't work
  });

}
```

How can I add, change or remove CSS attributes to a pseudo-element of `$(this)`?

Comment: Jason, It is not a duplicate. The duplicate just asks to change the content of the pseudo-element. I want to change the CSS attributes

Comment: Toggle a class instead and use relevant CSS rule to handle pseudo element, e.g `$(this).addClass('red');` and in CSS `.image.red:after {background-color: red;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle the ":after" pseudo-element because it *doesn't exists* in the DOM (same for :before). But you can *create* it using this:

```
$(element).after();
```

And then handle that with JS.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: How do I handle it? :p

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen Try to store it in a var and do something with that variable.